# javascript to get value from database onchange text field value

Tags: php, javascript, database

Well i am new here, and also new in web base programming  . i have a database for a shop, and now i'm make a site for that. In that database there is a table call stock in which every product has a id ,color,code and size. that color code and size is working as composite key.And also have a price.

now in my site i make a page "salse.php" where input will be code , color, size by select optons drop down menu

`<label for="code">Code</label>
            <select name="code" size="1" id="code">
                <option selected="selected">Choose One</option>
                    <option>L</option> 
                    <option>G</option>
                    <option>S</option>
                    <option>B</option>
             </select>`
like that.
[1] now i want that when user fill that 3 field code , color and size then my java script will automatic find the salse price from database, and place into price field.

[2] and after that when user fill that quantity label then automatically generate the total price by multiplying quantity field value with price field value and print inside total field.

I tried and here is my code

```
<this script will use to get price value -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
function price(str)
    {
    if (str =="")
    {
        price =document.getElementById('salse');
        price.value = Number (0);
        return;
    }
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState ==4 && xmlhttp.status ==200)
        {
            price =document.getElementById('salse');
            price.value = Number(xmlhttp.responseBody);
                    }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","price.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
  </script>
```

and the field is `<?php
                Echo " <label for='size'>Size</label>
            <select name='size' size='1' id='size' **onchange= 'price(this.value)**'> 
            <option selected='selected'>Choose Size</option>";
            $size = 0;
            while($size <= 50)
            {
                Echo"<option>";echo $size; Echo"</option>";
                $size++;
            }
            Echo"</select>";`
 and inside price.php this code is like 
`

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
     echo $row['salse_price'] ;

  }`
```

But the output is "undefined" .. please help to solve this, i can print a string but how i possibly change a value of a field .

```
`<this script will use when to get total value -->

    <label for="quantity">Q'ty</label>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="" /> <br> 
    <label for="salse">Salse Price:</label>
    <input type="text" name="salse" id="salse" size="20" value=""/>&nbsp;<br>
    <label for ="total">Total</label>
    <input type="text" name="total" id="total" size="20" value =""/><br>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x    = document.getElementById('quantity'),
        y    = document.getElementById('salse'),
        total = document.getElementById('total');

        function calculate_total(){
         // Use your real calculation here
        total.value = Number(x.value) * Number(y.value) ;
        }

     if( window.addEventListener ) {
       x.addEventListener('change', calculate_total, false);
       y.addEventListener('change', calculate_total, false);
     } else if(window.attachEvent){
        x.attachEvent('onchange', calculate_total);
        y.attachEvent('onchange', calculate_total);
      }
    </script> `
```

now can fill total label value by user input both quantity and price.. but can't check that 3 field value filled up or not, and also can't print the price value from database.

Answer (score 0):

You need a language/system that works server side, which pulls data and generates the HTML you will send to the client, like PHP, which you tagged.

[This website](http://www.w3schools.com/website/web_php_database.asp) is a good starting point for anything web.